# Tips panel for Typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I work with Typescript, its tooltips make my work very easy, but sometimes I miss them when using custom props. Is there any way to customize these small tooltips on the right side of the panel?

[when selecting a props - only the name is displayed on the right side, I would like to throw additional information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqbRS.png)

At first I thought to sign props with JSDoc, but it didn't give great results, I would like to have a hint exactly when selecting an option, like for example when selecting Tailwind classes [small text on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ2aj.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you just open the details panel of the suggestion widget, it'll show what you wrote in your JSDoc. Does that work for you? And if it does, is that sufficient for you?